# break down section and subsection as only section on the header on the beamer

Tags: beamer, formatting

How can we break down section and subsection as only section on the header on the beamer?

For example,

[image]

AA is from section and DATA is from subsection.

```
\section{AA}
\subsection{DATA}
```

Is it possible that 'AA DATA' appear on the center only using section?

```
\section{AA DATA}
```

Thank you,

Comment: I don't understand your question. Could you please elaborate a little more?

Comment: I am sorry but this is still not clear: "appear on the center only using section". Do you want all the headline to have just one color?

Comment: Hi, Gonzalo: Thank you so much for this answer. It works for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what you want:

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}
\usetheme{AnnArbor}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.65ex,dp=1.5ex,center]{section in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}\insertsectionhead\hspace*{2ex}
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}
\makeatother

\author{The Author}
\title{The Title}
\institute{The Institute}

\begin{document}

\section{AA DATA}
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I redefined the `headline` template to use just one `beamercolorbox` of width given by `\paperwidth` and containing just the name of the current section, centered.